# Get a php $_SESSION var in a javascript using a javascript var

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have some php `$_SESSION` vars that I am using in my site.  like follows

```
$_SESSION[$select_grid_name."_id"];
```

The grid name is a name of the table been targeted. This all seems to work well but I have one issue that now I am trying to get the session var on a javascript call which is generated programatically for all grids

I want to do something like this

```
var grid_name = sender["id"]; //id assigned form grid call on select
var field_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION[?>" +grid_name +"]; ?>";
```

this errors because I am breaking up the php `echo` call. How can I call the php session var based on the javascript grid name?

Comment: var means variables ??

Comment: @Jaykishan – You can't use referenced links syntax in comments; only `[text](url)` syntax works, but you can edit (for a couple of minutes) and delete your own comments instead of posting multiple ones.

Comment: @Jaykishan, he's trying to access a PHP variable with a JavaScript variable. It's a little different.

Comment: He has edited his question, at very first he was not clear about what he wants\

Answer (score 1):

**You simply cannot do that.**

Client side (JavaScript) variables are not sent to the server like that.

If you want PHP to be aware of variables set in JavaScript, you should look into making an [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Popular libs like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) will make easy work of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in html

```
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $select_grid_name; ?>" value="<?php  echo $_SESSION[$select_grid_name."_id"];?>"/>
```

in jquery

```
var grid_name = sender["id"]; 
var field_id = $("#"+grid_name).val();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
var grid_name = <?php echo sender["id"]?>
```

Comment: Because the grid_name is the name of the php $_SESSION var not the contents of the var. I am trying to get the contents of the $_SESSION named i.e grid_one where I know that grid_name = grid_one so the php SESSION would be $_SESSION["grid_one"]

Comment: my bad , so , haven't read enought.
So try to echo your php var in the js declaration